# Tracing the position of the images in the scrollview while scrolling

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I ve set of images (created dynamically) which are placed in a single row in my UIScrolView.. I want to trace the changes in the locations (i.e I want to get the x,y position of all the images)while scrolling ....

Things I ve tried:

1.I stored all the images in an array
2.Then I printed the locations of images in this delegate

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

But I can't get result what I want....Instead of that I get the positions of the images which I specified.....How can I get rid of this????

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean by the location of the images but I *think* you want the `contentOffset` property of `UIScrollView`. If you subtract the `x` and `y` values of that from the offset of the frames of your images then you will effectively get where the images are relative to your `UIScrollView`'s parent.

Edit: Here's some code to get you started:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    for (UIView *view in scrollView.subviews) {
        CGPoint thisOrigin = view.frame.origin;
        thisOrigin.x -= offset.x;
        thisOrigin.y -= offset.y;
        NSLog(@"thisOrigin = %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(thisOrigin));
    }
}
```

That will get the origin of the images in the coordinate system of the `UIScrollView`'s bounds. If you want just the origin of the images within the coordinate system of the `UIScrollView`'s contents then you just want `view.frame.origin` itself. But I don't think that's what you want since you said "But I can't get result what I want....Instead of that I get the positions of the images which I specified".

Comment: Location means x and y positions of the images

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested then? Should work I think. Assuming you want to get the location of the images in the coordinate system of the `UIScrollView`'s bounds.

Comment: But I found that my content offset values of both x and y are 0

Comment: The `contentOffset` of your `UIScrollView` will not be `{0, 0}` if you scroll. If it is, then you're looking at the wrong scroll view or not accessing the value properly.

Comment: Edited to add some code to show you what I mean. The "position" of your images depends on in what coordinate system you want. Hopefully what I've shown is what you want.